# Unable to use Internet (hosts unknown) after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 - DNS Resolv.conf problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager, resolv.conf

I upgraded my PC two days ago from 12.04 (desktop) to 14.04 (desktop).  Since then, I am unable to surf on the internet.  More exactly, I have the connection (wired) but not host resolving. I have tried several things without succes: static and dynamic IP, dnsmasq commented out,...
If I use DHCP on other computers on the same network, I have no problem.  On my Ubuntu, I see no error but I am unable to surf nor to resolve any host name.
For instance, I can ping to 192.168.2.1 and 8.8.8.8 (configured as names servers) but not to www.google.com nor google.com.  nslookup fails as well ('host unreachable').
After long searches, I found a problem in the '/etc/resolv.conf': If I do a 'cat /etc/resolv.conf', nothing is shown although it correctly points to '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf'.  I then copied that regular file to '/etc/resolv/conf' (not recommended, I know) and -bingo - everything runs fine.

Now the question is 'why does the symlink not work properly'?

Comment: 1-Can you get something from an host located in the local network ? For example `http://somemachine.local/anything`. If name resolution works on the local network, it must be a firewall problem. Does nslookup hang or tell something ?

Comment: Thank for comment.  I edited the post to reflect the actual situation: problem worked around but with a no so satisfying solution.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say more. On my installation the symlink works. Check the permissions ?

Comment: I also checked it.  No problem.  The problem comes from the symbolic link. I made a separate post for the question ([link]http://askubuntu.com/q/517663/320920)

Comment: Is the resolvconf package installed?

Comment: Is is.  I also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`, leading to the (re)creation of the symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf` to `../run/resolvconf/resovl.conf`.  Problem is that link leads to an empty file.  So far, I have two options to get DNs to work: 
1. Copy the plain file from `/run/resolconf/resol.conf` to `/etc/resolv.conf`
2. Manually create the symbolic link `/etc/resvol.conf` pointing to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`