# Symbolic link to resolv.conf strange behaviour in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dns, symbolic-link, resolv.conf

I recently upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 14.04.  I then experienced major problem in DNS resolution that did not work anymore.
I finally found the following: in /etc, there is a 'resolv.conf' wihich is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf.resolv.conf`.  On my system this is an empty file.
However, '/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf' is there.  I manually reated the symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. That works perfectly.  Howevrer the original link does not work.
To illustrate this, I created two symbolic links in '/etc':

```
marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ ls -irl dns.*
787036 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 aoû 29 17:50 dns.ok -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
787080 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 aoû 29 17:51 dns.nok -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ cat dns.ok
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ cat dns.nok
marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$
```

As you see, the second one is empty. Now, the question: Why is the original symlink pointing to the '../' (wrong) version?

Comment: The relative symbolic link (the one you say is wrong) works fine for me. What's the output of `ls -l /etc/../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`? Can you cat that file directly?

Comment: `marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ ls -l /etc/../run/resovlconf/resolv.conf
ls: impossible d'accéder à /etc/../run/resovlconf/resolv.conf: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`

But 

`marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ ls /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Comment: There's a typo: resovlconf instead of resolvconf in the first command you ran.

Comment: Right.  Here the right version + output of cat (both versions): `marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ ls -l /etc/../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 avr 23  2012 /etc/../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
marc@marc-Vostro-420-Series:/etc$ cat /etc/../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if your DNS is being managed by the resolveconf package (the default for 14.04). If you need to add nameservers, add them to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and restart resolvconf `service resolvconf restart` and it will rebuild the /etc/resolv.conf "file".

Comment: Why is it normal that the link `dns.nok`, equivalent to the one created by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` points to an empty file and the other one (`dns.ok`) points to the file I would have expected to?